# Ошибка подключения к MongoDB через localhost

Tags: mongodb

> НЕ ясно как передать параметр параметр { useUnifiedTopology: true }
> И как изменить JSON.stringfy

```
/*
//Перевод текста ошибки.
Предупреждение об устаревании: текущий механизм обнаружения и мониторинга серверов устарел и будет удален в будущей версии. Чтобы использовать новый механизм обнаружения и мониторинга серверов, передайте параметр { useUnifiedTopology: true } конструктору MongoClient.
TypeError: JSON.stringfy - это не функция
*/
let client = require ('mongodb').MongoClient; // client объект для присоединения и работы с базой; 'mongodb' драйвер; MongoClient методы для соед с БД выполнения запросов и др операций
const connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017"; //адресс для подключения к MongoDB
(async () =>{ //асинхронный метод (для чего асинхронный)?      
        let connection = await client.connect(connectionString, {useNewUrlParser:true});  //как бы переменная для подключения к БД               
        let db = connection.db('usersdb');  //если базы с таким названием нет то она просто создастся и мы будем с ней работать
        try{
            let user = {name:'Ivan', age:25};
            const result = await  db.collection('users').insertOne(user);           
            console.log(JSON.stringfy(result));       
        }finally{             
            connection.close(); //соединение закроется независимо будет ошибка или нет       
        }   
    })().catch(error => console.log(error));

/*


*/
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опечатка в `JSON.stringify()`. Там нету ошибки подключения, есть просто предупреждение. Добавьте в параметры `userUnifiedTopology: true`.

Comment: Спасибо, предупреждений больше нет